# Install Raspbian packages directly from Ubuntu with chroot to Raspbian file system (on SD card)

Tags: raspbian, apt, ubuntu

I'm connecting to internet with my pc using Ethernet cable, I just have  one internet cable input and one RJ45 cable, so I cant share internet with my Raspberry.

is there any solution to install Rapsbian packages from Ubuntu by just accessing Raspbian SD card on Ubuntu and using `chroot` command, and run `apt-get` as though I'm on raspberry??

Comment: do they sell routers, switches and hubs in your country? get one and share the internet connection.

Comment: I believe you can tell apt-get to download a specific architecture. Obviously, you'd have to add the Raspbian archives to your system and then run apt-get specifically targeting the RPis arch, but it *should* be doable.

Comment: When I first got my Pi I went down this route, downloading individual .deb packages and copying them onto the SD card then booting the Pi then installing them only to find I was missing just one more dependency. usb wifi is very cheap and a better long term solution.

Comment: @rob yes this is the problem, I want to use usb wifi, but before i should install driver, so I would use the sd card on ubuntu to install the driver

Comment: a number of the usb wifi devices work out of the box. I have a Tenda device id 148f:5370 that just works and another (make) that does not work on the Pi until I have connected via ethernet and run sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, install two packages on your Ubuntu system: `qemu-user`, and `proot`.

After you mount the Raspbian SD card, you can do the equivalent of a 'chroot' with:

```
sudo proot -q qemu-arm -S /mnt/path/to/raspbian/
```

From there, you can use `apt-get` commands as though you are actually on the Raspberry Pi. (Use the `exit` command to exit.)

Comment: I got this error with `-S` option `proot error: unknown option -S.
proot error: see proot --help or man proot.`
 i removed `-S` and apt-get not working ,????

Comment: Bah, `proot` keeps changing their commandline options. If one of the following forms of the command works for you, let us know. `sudo proot -q qemu-arm -B -r /mnt/path/to/raspbian/` or `sudo proot -Q qemu-arm -r /mnt/path/to/raspbian/`

Comment: `sudo proot -q qemu-arm -B -r ./rootfs-mnt` did the job for me on Raspbian 2015-05-05